# Power BI Report Not Visible

Tags: sharepoint-online, reports, powerbi

I have a small problem hat i am facing currently, this involves Power Bi. I am trying to view my report on Sharepoint Online Site Page and the report is also visible but the problem is it is only visible to me and to no one else !

How can i solve this?
Any help would be great !

Answer (score 1):

That sounds very much like a licensing issue. As I recall it you must have an E5 or a explicit Power BI license in order to view the Content.
Try to assign such a license to one of your users to verify if it is a licensing issue

Comment: i did assigning the access to one user and it said i had to buy the pro version.
i am not seeing the publish to web option also.
could you help me out as to how can i get publish to web option in this ?

Comment: @jayantkhushalani "With sharing, whether you share content inside or outside your organization, you need a Power BI Pro license. Your recipients also need Power BI Pro licenses, or the content needs to be in a Premium capacity."  - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-share-dashboards

Comment: i have a free pro version but i cannot see the publish to web option also.
is this also a licensing issue?

Comment: You need to also share the dashboard.  It won't just work with sharepoint permissions unless you want to use 'publish to web' option which will make the url publicly accessible

Answer (score 1):

Like Kasper said it is most likely a licensing issue, here is a link to the Power BI documentation that explains the licensing needed for sharing content in Power BI. Depending on what and how you are sharing both the person sharing and the recipient might need premium licenses.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-share-dashboards